# Int to numeric conversion error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a question with converting data. I have a select query made in VBA, how can I convert from `varchar` value column to `nvarchar`.

I get this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

This is my code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

 strSQL = " INSERT INTO dbo.Soferi_test (test1)" & _
       " SELECT MySQL.dbo.sofieri.certificat_cipti " & _
       " FROM  MySQL.dbo.sofieri " & _
       " WHERE IDNO = " & Forms!Forma_redactare_soferi!IDNO.Value

 Call AttServ(strSQL, rst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your int value is too big for the numeric precision and scale definition

Here, I guess the error comes from the WHERE clause. Not the INSERT

```
DECLARE @foo int = 99999;
DECLARE @n1 numeric(9,1), @n2 numeric (3,2);

-- 9,1 is 9 total digits, 1 decimal place
-- 3,2 is 2 total digits, 2 decimal places

-- 99999 requires at least 5 total digits

PRINT 'Wide enough'
SET @n1 = @foo;


PRINT 'Error'
SET @n2 = @foo;
```

After comment, the same still applies

```
DECLARE @foo numeric(5,0) = 99999;
DECLARE @n1 numeric(9,1), @n2 numeric (3,2);

PRINT 'Wide enough'
SET @n1 = @foo;


PRINT 'Error'
SET @n2 = @foo;
```

Comment: sorry i had mistake its numeric to data type numeric in my error not INT

Comment: @Sergio: the same applies.

Comment: how can i update this statments in vba? i am new one in Vba and in sql

Comment: You will have to ensure the datatypes in the WHERE clause match between VBA and SQL